# How to use preg match to get the contents of this html tag?

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to get at the desired content in this tag:

```
<p class="address">
desired content
</p>
```

this is my attempt:

```
preg_match_all("/\<p class=\"address\">(.*)\<\/p\>/", $contents, $matches);
```

But the $matches array is empty. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: [xpath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html) [alternative:](https://gist.github.com/1358174) `xpath_match_all('//p[@class="address"]', $html);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$contents = '<p class="address">desired content</p>';
$res = preg_match_all("/\<p class=\"address\">(.*)\<\/p\>/s", $contents, $matches);
var_dump($res);
var_dump($matches);
```

$matches is not empty, right?

Comment: you're missing the line breaks.

Comment: Try something like this: $res = preg_match_all("/\<p class=\"address\">(.*)\<\/p\>/s", $contents, $matches);

Comment: As far as I remember in seach function in php /m modifier is used by default, you need use explicity /s modifier when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to set the PCRE_DOTALL flag to make `.` also match `\n` - see [modifiers](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)
2. use `.*?` (ungreedy operator) to not prevent matching `</p>` in the capture group
3. you can use a different pattern delimiter and single quotes to remove all the backslashes, makes your pattern much more readable!

like so:

```
<?php
$contents = '<p class="address">
desired content
</p>';
$res = preg_match_all('#<p class="address">(.*?)</p>#s', $contents, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```